# How to combine row and Column with different size in a cell array into matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

How to efficiently combined cell `array` v `row` and `Column` with different size into a `matrix`, filling the vectors   with 0? 
for For example, if I have

```
A= {[1;2;3]  [1 2 ; 1 3; 2 3]  [1 2 3]};
```

**I'd like to get either:**

```
A=[1 0 0
   2 0 0
   3 0 0
   1 2 0
   1 3 0
   2 3 0
   1 2 3]
```

Comment: but your answer was worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simply `padarray` to pad your arrays with zeros before `vertcat` them:

```
  B = padarray(A{1},[0 3-size(A{1},2)],'post')
  C = padarray(A{2},[0 3-size(A{2},2)],'post')
  D = padarray(A{3},[0 3-size(A{3},2)],'post')
  %//Note the 3-size(A{1},2)... The 3 comes from the number of columns you want your final matrix to be, and it cannot be smaller than the maximum value of size(A{N},2) in your case it is 3, since A{3} is 3 columns wide. 
  result = vertcat (B,C,D)

  result =

     1     0     0
     2     0     0
     3     0     0
     1     2     0
     1     3     0
     2     3     0
     1     2     3
```

you can write a loop to iterate through your cell or use a cellfun to parallelize.

In a simple loop, it looks like:

```
 result = [];
 for t = 1:size(A,2)
    B = padarray(A{t},[0 3-size(A{t},2)],'post');
    result = vertcat(result,B);
 end
```

Comment: sorry when I change cell array to bigger cell array matlab has error